# How to query by time in MongoDB with PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, mongodb

I want to query a collection and get documents which have created less than 3 hours ago.

```
$realtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$mongotime = New Mongodate(strtotime($realtime));

$mongotime = $mongotime - 3 hours; //PSEUDOCODE
$some_condition = array('time' => array('$lt'=>$mongotime) );

$result = $db->collection->find( $some_condition );
```

Is there an effective way to put

> $some_condition

part without using IF statement in PHP?

Comment: I don't see any if statement in your code... is this really what your code looks like?

Comment: I think you also have the order of your condition wrong. `$lt` reads left to right, so you want the PHP equivalent of `{time: {$lt: mongotime}}`, which would be `array('time'=>array('$lt'=>$mongotime))`

Comment: @drcosta no this is just a pseudocode that I'm trying to do. Instead of using Find(), get value from query result and determine the condition by that value, I want to get qualifying results right away without using any If statement in PHP.

Comment: I don't understand. If you can show your actual code, we'll probably be able to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution.

```
$diff = 60 * 60 * 3; //3 hours in seconds

$mongotime = New Mongodate(time()-$diff);

$condition = array('time' => array('$lt'=>$mongotime) );

$result = $db->collection->find( $condition );
```

Comment: Your calculation of `$realtime` is wasteful, you could just do `$mongotime = new MongoDate(time()-$diff);`

Comment: For latest php version Mongodate class is deprecated. can you give example with latest php version

Answer (score 1):

First get the time three hours before now. Then query larger than that time:

```
define('SECONDS_PER_HOUR', 3600);

$mongotime = New Mongodate(time()-3*SECONDS_PER_HOUR);

$condition = array('time' => array('$lt'=>$mongotime));

$result = $db->collection->find($condition);
```

There is no need to do some timestamp -> string -> timestamp conversion (as you suggested it) and you should name the constants you use so it's clear what they represent.